# Zope/Plone If Statement Evaluation

Tags: zope, dtml

I have two very distinct regions of my page that I would like to swap between based on a the setting of a dtml-var.

The variable is loaded when the page is built and is called GENDER_DESC.  I can display the contents with `<dtml-var GENDER_DESC>`, the GENDER_DESC object will either be null, Female or Male.

What I would like to do is have a dtml-if statement that switches the content based on the state of that GENDER_DESC variable.

I have tried something like this:

```
<dtml-if expr="GENDER_DESC = 'Female'">
    <img src="student_photo?key=&dtml-SID;" style="height:140px; width:190px; border:5px solid black "/>
</dtml-if>
```

And a few other variations on that concept, but I cannot get the syntax correct.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTML expressions need to be valid Python. In Python, "=" is the assignment operator. You probably want to test equality; the operator for that is "==".

Comment: Great, thanks!  I didn't know that those expressions needed to be python as well.